# How to filter a product collection based on product type and its attribute value?

Tags: magento

Let's say in one category I have simple products and virtual products. Now for logged in and non-logged in customers, I want to filter the products to display under that category. I have no problem with the logged in and non-logged in condition. The problem is with the collection filter.

Let's say I have a "filesize" attribute for the virtual products. By observing the `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event, I want to filter so that non-logged in customers can see all simple products plus virtual products with filesize = 1,2 (it means 1MB and 2MB, multiselect attribute). And all logged-in customers can see all simple products plus virtual products with all filesize.

My collection code for non-logged in customers is like this:

```
$observer->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('filesize','type_id')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('filesize', array('in' => array(1,2)));
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('filesize','type_id')
           ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'type_id','eq' => 'simple')))
           ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'filesize','in' => array(1,2))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection

> Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_collection_load_before', array('collection' => $this));

So in your observer try

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('filesize','type_id')
           ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))
           ->addAttributeToFilter('filesize', array('in' => array(1,2)));
```

Comment: I got the same error, **Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object**. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070652/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object-in or  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5745/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object